# Importing a xlsx from a url into google sheets

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-apps

In GoogleDocs, I'm trying to use an import function (e.g. =importdata) to extract data from or open an online XLSX file.  An example would be the url below:

http://www.sportsbookreviewsonline.com/scoresoddsarchives/nba/nba%20odds%202015-16.xlsx

Ideally I want this to automatically upload this file everytime I open google sheets. The data comes back corrupted however it does mention a .xml location.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your efforts so far.

Comment: thanks! seems like an amazing site! i've tried using importdata however this results in corrupted text. i feel that its an xml file even though its .xlsx due to the first line in sheets when using importdata. i've tried an importxml function however that didn't working as there is no clear xpath query